# Images in Unity, only recent image is displayed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I creating a game in Unity where the player is able to take photos from a polaroid camera, the polaroids will drop down on the ground. From here the player is able to pick them up and view them.

I am able to take the pictures and interact with the polaroid, the only problem now is that the same image is displayed on all polaorids on the ground. The recently taken image is the one which is displayed.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PhotoCapture:MonoBehaviour {
    [Header("Photo Taker")]
    [SerializeField] public Image photoDisplayArea;
    [SerializeField] public GameObject photoFrame;

    [Header("Flash Effect")]    
    [SerializeField] private GameObject cameraFlash;
    [SerializeField] private float flashTime;

    private Texture2D screenCapture;
    public static bool viewingPhoto = false;

    // All text GUI needs to be in this parent object
    [Header("GUI")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject GUI;

    [Header("Polaroid GameObject")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject itemPolaroid;

    [Header("Controls")]
    //[SerializeField] private KeyCode useCamera = KeyCode.Mouse0;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode closePicture = KeyCode.Mouse1;

    // Raycast
    private RaycastHit hitObject;
    private bool itemObject = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {
        screenCapture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(PlayerActions.useCameraButton) && ItemCamera.canUseCamera && !viewingPhoto) {
            StartCoroutine(CapturePhoto());
        }

        itemObject = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hitObject, 6f);
        if(!viewingPhoto && Input.GetKeyDown(PlayerActions.actionButton) && itemObject && hitObject.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Polaroid")) {
            ShowPhoto();
        }

        if(viewingPhoto && Input.GetKeyDown(closePicture)) {
            RemovePhoto();
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Increases light intensity on object - CameraFlash
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IEnumerator CameraFlashEffect() {
        cameraFlash.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(flashTime);
        cameraFlash.SetActive(false);
    }

    private IEnumerator CapturePhoto() {
        // CameraUI set false
        GUI.SetActive(false);

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        Rect regionToRead = new(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
        screenCapture.ReadPixels(regionToRead, 0, 0, false);
        screenCapture.Apply();

        // Makes a sprite of the screenshot and places it in PhotoDisplayArea in ItemPolaroidObject
        Sprite photoSprite = Sprite.Create(screenCapture, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, screenCapture.width, screenCapture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);
        photoDisplayArea.sprite = photoSprite;

        StartCoroutine(CameraFlashEffect());
        GUI.SetActive(true);
        SpawnItemPolaroid();
    }

    public void ShowPhoto() {
        viewingPhoto = true;
        GUI.SetActive(false);
        // Sets PhotoFrameBG (Blank canvas) in ItemPolaroidObject to true
        photoFrame.SetActive(true);
    }

    private void RemovePhoto() {
        viewingPhoto = false;
        photoFrame.SetActive(false);
        GUI.SetActive(true);
    }

    // Bug - becomes a clone of original object and change with the original
    private void SpawnItemPolaroid() {
        GameObject newPolaroid = Instantiate(itemPolaroid, new Vector3(Random.Range(FirstPersonController.characterController.transform.position.x - 0.5f, FirstPersonController.characterController.transform.position.x + 0.5f), Random.Range(FirstPersonController.characterController.transform.position.y + 0.5f, FirstPersonController.characterController.transform.position.y + 1.5f), Random.Range(FirstPersonController.characterController.transform.position.z - 0.5f, FirstPersonController.characterController.transform.position.z + 0.5f)), Quaternion.identity);

    }
}
```

I have tried setting the photoDisplayArea and photoFrame to every new clone but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only assign to "screenCapture" in the start method, so when you create a new image with Sprite.Create you end up referencing the same Texture2D instance that Unity then uses to draw the in game texture for all the photos.

Solution:

To fix this, you could simply create a new Texture2D in "CapturePhoto()" and assign it to "screenCapture".

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to create a new texture everytime you want to take screenshot.

```
screenCapture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
screenCapture.ReadPixels(regionToRead, 0, 0, false);
screenCapture.Apply();
```

Too many textures can consume too much memory, so if your game often crashes, consider [saving the texture to a file](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.EncodeToJPG.html) and [reading them](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.LoadImage.html) when you need to display them to the player.